# Is it possible to start a server in Zapier Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, zapier

We need to send an HTTP CODE = 200 with a body 'OK' in reply to a notification through Zapier.

Is it possible to use the following code in Zapier:

```
var http = require('http');
  const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.end('OK');
}).listen(80);
```

It returns an error:

```
Error: You did not define `output`! Try `output = {id: 1, hello: "world"};`
```

And the reply doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you trying to start a server? Just execute the response handler

Comment: @Tyrsius You mean only `res.statusCode = 200; res.end('OK');`?

Comment: @Tyrsius Otherwise it throws a reference error, like http is not defined or res is not defined

Comment: No, I mean why are you trying start an http server _at all_? You don't need to listen for http events, zapier code provides the input as an object. You don't need to respond with an http event either, zapier provides and `output` and an async `callback`.

Comment: @Tyrsius But the problem is that I had to send a custom response to the webhook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

To cut to the chase - though it might be possible to start an http server (there's no reason it wouldn't be, as far as I know), it's not going to do what it seems like you're hoping to do. Namely, you can't send a custom response to an incoming webhook. From the [docs](https://zapier.com/help/webhooks/#why-is-it-always-200-or-success-status-can-i-customize-the-response):

> There is no way to customize the response to the request you send to the Catch Hook URL, as the response is sent before the Zap triggers and runs on the webhook request.

If you need behavior like that, I'd suggest running a webserver.

The specific Code step error you're seeing has to do with not defining output to the function. Something goes in and something must come out. You can customize the output based on the input and use that output, but something has to be returned from the function (even if it's just `{}`).

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much! Do you mean, that it's not possible at all to send a custom response through Zapier? Even if we build a custom app using zapier-platform-cli?

Comment: Correct. There's nothing you can do on Zapier today that allows you to send a custom response to a webhook.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!